# Prometheus Query - Group by values and return a count

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I have a metric that returns a few unique values for each timeseries. (This is from Prometheus Blackbox Exporter). See example below

[image]

How can I group these by value and return a count. The following is the expected outcome

```
{status="400"}      1
{status="0"}        0
{status="200"}      2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following PromQL:

```
count_values("status", probe_http_status_code)
```

More info in Prometheus documentation [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators).